# On my cherry tree new growth the leaves curl, are black underneath at start. Eventually the leaves turn black and dry out before falling to the ground

Tags: trees

I had a plum tree last year which had similar symptoms. Eventually the entire tree died. That tree was adjacent to the cherry.
I have removed all badly infected leaves and twigs and applied a fungus spray.
Have I done the right thing, and how can I prevent it happening next season

Comment: A photo would be helpful - what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Take a look at the photos at this site. Do they resemble your trees? https://pnwhandbooks.org/plantdisease/host-disease/cherry-prunus-spp-cherry-mottle-leaf